# Is guava ImmutableSet.copyOf() thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, guava

I would like to know if this call is thread safe. For example, if I have a set s:

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<>();
```

and two threads A and B, thread A modifying the set:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1234; i++) {
    // add, remove from s
}
```

while thread B creating ImmutableSets from s:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5678; i++) {
    Set<String> newS =  ImmutableSet.copyOf(s);
}
```

Is it safe to assume that each time `ImmutableSet.copyOf()` is called I get an immutable set for a valid state of s in time? Will there be any kind of exception (like `ConcurrentModificationException`) that can occur?

If it is thread safe, how was it achieved without locking the set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relevant question isn't whether `copyOf` is safe -- it's whether the collection it's copying *from* is safe, and in particular, whether the Iterators that it creates via its `iterator()` method are thread-safe. For HashMap, that answer is no.

Answer (score 5):

`HashSet` isn't thread safe. `ImmutableSet.copyOf` needs to iterate over your `HashSet`, which isn't safe if another thread is concurrently modifying it. What's more, your having two threads modifying the `HashSet` is already unsafe.

Comment: I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900147/send-record-and-wait-for-its-acknowledgement-to-receive) in which I am using guava and I am not sure whether those operations are working correctly or not so wanted to see if you can help me out.

Comment: HashSet is NOT thread-safe even if nobody modifies it in the same time. HashSet access always needs to be synchronized.